# value error with tensorflow's tf.round() as it's an operation without a gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code

```
    pred_raw = create_feedforward_nn_model(x, weights, biases)
    pred = tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid(pred_raw))
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=pred, logits=y))
    train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

Here, `create_feedforward_nn_model` just create a 2 layered feed forward DNN and returns the last layer(which is logits).  so, when i run this code, i get the following error,

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables 
["<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(28, 20) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(20, 8) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=(8, 1) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_3:0' shape=(20,) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_4:0' shape=(8,) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'Variable_5:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>"] 
and loss Tensor("Mean_8:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).
```

So, i played around and found that `tf.round` is causing this problem because, when i ran it changing the following line

```
pred = tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid(pred_raw))
```

to

```
pred = tf.nn.sigmoid(pred_raw)
```

it's working properly.

shouldn't `tf.round` support gradient too? am i missing something here?

I am using **Tensorflow version 1.4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a gradient for `round` since the function is piecewise-constant and non-continuous. That is, for any range where the result would be the same (e.g. the range `(0.5, 1.5)`) the gradient would be 0, and it would be undefined at the border values (0.5, 1.5 etc.). In any case, a gradient of 0 is not useful.

I think you are mixing up some stuff in your code. In binary classification, you do want class outputs at the end (i.e. 0 or 1), but for training you will generally want to use the continous probabilities. That is, the sigmoid outputs *without* rounding. In addition to that, the built-in Tensorflow cross-entropy losses actually apply the sigmoid internally and expect the *pre-sigmoid* values (logits), which is sorta implied by their names (e.g. `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`). So in your snippet you should pass `logits = pred_raw` to the loss.

BTW you also mixed up `labels` and `logits` -- `logits` are your model outputs, `labels` the real labels.